# Iterate over array in proxy

Tags: javascript

Good day.

I was testing stuff in Javascript with Proxies.

Currently I have this [proxy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jy40N.png)

My question was, how do I iterate over this? I've tried several methods, including object.keys and forEach, which yielded nothing.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you should show your code, not a picture of a console.log if you require assitance

Comment: I figured in this instance that it didn't quite matter, as I was only asking about how to iterate over this.

Comment: I'm a bit rusty on proxies, but presumably it depends on how the proxy is configured and what the target object is?

Comment: @jopfrenken - you figured incorrectly :p

Comment: @jopfrenken "*I was only asking about how to iterate over this.*" well the "this" is a screenshot. You don't generally iterate over screenshots. If you mean the data, then do include it as text in the question. And indicate what and why failed, because *based on the screenshot*, I do not see why `.forEach` would not work. But I if you say it doesn't, I've no idea why it would be. Maybe you just had a typo. Maybe it's something to do with the proxy. Without a [mcve] we can only guess. Moreover, future visitors would have to make their own guesses which makes the Q&A quite useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify an [`ownKeys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy/ownKeys) method in the handler you're using to create the proxy or you won't be able to enumerate the keys of the proxy object.

```js
const obj = { test: 'a' };
const handler1 = {
  ownKeys(target) {
    return Reflect.ownKeys(target);
  }
};

const proxy1 = new Proxy(obj, handler1);
console.log(Object.keys(proxy1)) // ['test']
```

### Edit

Actually, you can use `Reflect.ownKeys` directly also, but you'll want to make sure the behavior is what you expect. For example, it might return `length` as a key as well.